# Why TreeView node.text show strange structure in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview, tooltip

I have a treeview

```
Microsoft.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView myTreeView = new Microsoft.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView();
        myTreeView.Nodes.Clear();
```

And after populate data to the treeview I can show it nicely. However now I want to get the text in each branch of that tree (from root to parents to child in deepest level), and compare, if it is a certain name I will mark it as selected.

```
Microsoft.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNodeCollection nodes = myTreeView.Nodes;
        foreach (Microsoft.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode n in nodes)
        {
            string nodetext = n.Text;
            if (nodetext == "Casting")
                myTreeView.SelectedNodeIndex = n.GetNodeIndex();
        }
```

However when I print `nodetext`, I get very confuse with its value:

```
<acronym Title='Casting, Closed Die Press Forging, Compression Moulding, Drop Forging, Injection Moulding, Moulding Compounds, Steel Atomisation, Transfer Moulding, Two Shot Moulding, Upset Forging, Vacuum Forming'>Casting, Moulding, Forming, & Forging</acronym>
```

While in display, it show a tree in this format:

[image]

Why the text has that format and how could I extract exactly the each branch name as in the image? And is it right to turn the selected feature as I do above ?

Comment: Are you working on a windows app or web application ?

Comment: It is web application. I don't know why the node.text include <acronym> tag around the text. I just want to get the text in between this tag.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. In other part of the code they append the nodetext for the tree by

```
return String.Format("<acronym Title='{0}'>{1}</acronym>",
```

that is why it has that format. To get the text, I just have to use regex:

```
//get text inside tag
            string regularExpressionPattern1 = @"<acronym .*?>(.*?)<\/acronym>";
            Regex regex = new Regex(regularExpressionPattern1, RegexOptions.Singleline);
            MatchCollection collection = regex.Matches(n.Text.ToString());
            Match m = collection[0];
            var stripped = m.Groups[1].Value;
```

Thanks for your attention! Hope that would help some one has something related.